# Regular expression that ONLY accept letters and white spaces

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a function that validates user entered input and it checks the format, when my code runs, if the user only enters letters or numbers the regular expression works. But if the user enters a combination of words and letters, the output is "correct format" when the output should be "incorrect format"

```js
function nameValidation(){

    // Grabs name from the input box.
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;

    var format = /[^0-9]+/g;

    var match = format.test(name);

    if(match){
        alert("correct format");
    } else {
        alert("incorrect format");
    }
}
```

if user enters "abcdef" output is"correct format"
if user enters "123" output is "incorrect format"
if user enters "adbda1234" output is "correct format"
output should be "incorrect format"

Comment: Your regular expression will match any string that contains at least one non-digit character. You probably want to include the anchors `^` at the start and `$` at the end. However even then there are many characters that are not digits but also not letters and space characters.

Comment: You could use one of the many regex builder websites. Like regex101 or regexer?

Comment: `/^[a-z\s]+$/i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly want to only accept letters and white space, you'll want `[a-zA-Z]+\s*`

However, like the comments say, there are likely other cases to account for, so definitely look into a site like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to play around with your results.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question you only need to match letters and spaces.

Below regular expression will solve your question.

`/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/g`

Description of above reg exp:

1) ^ checks if string starts with letter or space.

2) $ checks if string ends with letter or space.

3) + checks if string has one or more letter or space.